# Wait for completion on streaming asyncio tasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am streaming json lines from a very large file, and processing the items in batches. The `get_batch_from_file` method yields a batch of items from the file. The `_process_batch` method includes some calls to mongodb, which I have made asynchronous using motor and asyncio. I am using semaphore to limit the concurrency to 10.

My problem is that the final log "Completed processing all" runs when the final batch starts instead of when it finishes. What am I missing to make this code wait for all the tasks to complete? Normally I would use
`asyncio.gather()` on a list of tasks, but the file is too large to do that.

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

for batch in get_batch_from_file():
    await sem.acquire()
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(_process_batch(batch))
    task.add_done_callback(lambda t: sem.release())
    
logger.info(f"Completed processing all")
```